# boost .ipp file support in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, boost

**{NOTE}: Visual Studio Dos support .ipp file. The problem here is more manual inefficiency rather than technical.**

In a C++ project there are few .ipp etensions files. While compiling in visual C++ 2008, i see some linker errors `"LNK2019: unresolved external symbol"`. I figured, for some object file linker was not able to link few function which were implemented under .ipp file. I included .ipp files under project (earlier they were not) but still the same issue.

My question is does visual C++ 2008 does not support .ipp file? If it does whats the right way to resolve these linker errors.

EDIT 1:
I found [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/boost@lists.boost.org/msg10544.html) link that supposedly should provide a workaround to make *.ipp work for visual C++. But, i am using Visual C++ 2008 and see registry path do not have "Languages\File Extensions" field as what this link says.

Comment: Sure, you can - compiler doesn't care about the extension. But is it a header or a translation unit? What do you see in this file?

Comment: The registry key you found could help you just to "colorize" the ipp in the editor. It can be done in MSVC2008 through "Options" menu, and it's unrelated to the compiler.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with filename extensions.  You can't get help without properly documenting your question, you must post the full error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `*.ipp` is a header file, you don't need to include it into the project -- just add the appropriate `#include` directive, where needed.

If it's a translation unit, i.e. you want to compile it, then add it to the project, right-click on it, in the property page go to "General", set "Item type" to be "C/C++ compiler".

Comment: This [http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2003/08/51197.php] is what a boost-pro has to say about *.ipp file. Tottaly confusing. it seems like *.ipp is queer version of .cpp and .hpp

Comment: @HokageSama ok, if ipp has template implementation only, it's not a separate translation unit, and should be eventually #included somewhere. But perhaps the `ipp` of the TS contains some other definitions - we can't know that.

Comment: *.ipp is #included in the same name *.hpp file. in linux compilation with gcc i dont see any issue. dont know., Why visual C++ doesnt recognize this file.

Comment: @HokageSama What do you mean by saying "doesn't recognize"? VC does *compile* this file, because it's included into hpp, which is included in some cpp. I suggest you to edit your question, specifying what symbol is undefined, and how it's mentioned in the ipp.

Comment: When i say 'not recognized' that would mean that all syntax in that file are uncolored. no tagging works. It seems to be plain txt file opened in VC. 

If *.ipp got included with *.hpp file then i think, i should not see any linking isue in msvc while it works fine with gcc in linux. am i wrong?

Comment: @HokageSama you mix 2 different topics. To get `ipp` colored, go to tools->options->project and solution->vc++ settings and include `ipp` in the relevant lists. As for linking, please ask the right question: *what* symbol the linker doesn't find and how its defined in the ipp, etc.

Comment: I havn't tried including ipp in option pane. I assumed this file might be treated as plain txt file and compiler might have rejected this file. But i guess you are right, because if compiler would have not recognized it as a valid C++ file, it should have shown compiler error when it was #included in *.hpp file. currently i do not have access to source code, will try it later today and will put my inputs. I will change the question accordingly as you have said. Thanks for bearing me.

Comment: @HokageSama Cool! Note that header file extension doesn't matter -- actually, most of std headers doesn't have extension at all (see #include <iostream> etc).

Comment: You were right Igor. Everytime i was seeing one file which has included ipp file but problem was in another similar kind of name file, where there was no .ipp file included. Thanks for guiding me through this.

Comment: Link correction for the Boost explanation of the `*.ipp` extension posted by @HokageSama: https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2003/08/51197.php

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but it still shows up in search results.

The solution for this is

1. To open the options screen
2. Search for 'file extension' in the search field
3. Type "ipp" (no quotes) in the extension field
4. Select "Visual C++" as the editor
5. Click Add, then Ok
6. Close and reopen any open ipp files

You'll get C++ syntax highlighting.